# Remove keywords which are not bigram or trigram (Yake)

Tags: python, dataframe, keyword, n-gram

I am using Yake (Yet Another Keyword Extractor) to extract keywords from a dataframe.
I want to extract only bigrams and trigrams, but Yake allows only to set a max ngram size and not a min size. How do you would remove them?

Example df.head(0):

Text:
'oui , yes , i mumbled , the linguistic transition now in limbo .'

Keywords:
'[('oui', 0.04491197687864554),
('linguistic transition', 0.09700399286574239),
('mumbled', 0.15831692877998726)]'

I want to remove oui, mumbled and their scores from keywords column.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is that the keywords list contains some monograms, you can simply do a filter that ignores words without spaces and create a new list. I'll give you an example:

```
keywords_without_unigrams = []
for kw in keywords:
    if(' ' in kw[0]):
        keywords_without_unigrams.append(kw)
 

for kw in keywords_without_unigrams:
    print(kw)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the handle the mono-gram case from Yake just pass the output through a filter that adds the n-grams to the result list only if there is a space in the first element of that tuple or if the str.split() of that element results in more than 1 sub-element. If you're using a function and applying it to the dataframe, include this step in that function.